# How can I make a program that tells me the repeated values ​within a list and tells you where the repeated values ​are?

Tags: python, list, function

I'm starting learning Python and I have to get this code working for a homework.

Here is what I have done

```
#Presentation
print("This program find all the repeated values ​​in a list and they tell you in what position they are")
print("First you have to make a list for that tell me")
#Input
elements=int(input("How many items does this list have? "))#Only for int
print("Tell me the items on this list")
list=[]
repeated=[]
counter=0
while counter != elements:
    a=int(input("=>"))#It only accepts integers but you have to be able to add any element
    list.append(a)
    counter=counter+1
    
#From here we already insert a list with n elements and name each element
    
#Now we have to see if there are repeated values
n=0
k=0
while k != elements:
    for i in list:
        if i == list[k]:
            n=n+1
    repeated.append(k)
    print (list[k],"repeated",n,"times")
    script=list[k]
    print(list[k],"is on the position number",list.index(script))
    n=0       
    k=k+1
```

I researched and I know that there are easier ways to do it by creating a dictionary to know how many times an element is repeated, but I still cannot use it since I have not been taught in the course I am taking

The only problems I have at the moment are
-How to make it only appear once how many times it is repeated?
-How to know in which position are all the repeats and not just the first one?

Here is an example of what this program currently prints

```
This program find all the repeated values ​​in a list and they tell you in what position they are
First you have to make a list for that tell me

How many items does this list have? 7
Tell me the items on this list

=>3

=>5

=>4

=>5

=>5

=>2

=>3
3 repeated 2 times
3 is on the position number 0
5 repeated 3 times
5 is on the position number 1
4 repeated 1 times
4 is on the position number 2
5 repeated 3 times
5 is on the position number 1
5 repeated 3 times
5 is on the position number 1
2 repeated 1 times
2 is on the position number 5
3 repeated 2 times
3 is on the position number 0
```

Although I am learning very basic things for now, if you can also leave a more optimized and simple way to solve this problem, even if it is more advanced, it would be very helpful, I am curious but also because I want to learn more.

Comment: Where are the comments for down rating this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your support, I found how to solve it and I share what I learned.

- If you are looking to find the position of repeated values ​​in a list using list.index
  it will only tell you where the first element is, not all of them.
- Using functions is very useful for complex jobs (perhaps this is not the best example) and it helps you to give a better order to what you do so it is recommended to get used to using these functions since it also gives you the opportunity for the user can generate your own variables.
- Taking breaks is good, it helps you rest your mind and gives you the opportunity to think better about the solutions you are looking for and how to simplify problems that you wanted to solve in a complex way.
- stack **overflow** is a good resource to learn new things and find different solutions from what you thought

Here's the code

```
#Función
def count_repeated(list,value):
    position=[]
    index=0

    for element in list:
        if element == value:
            position.append(index)
        index +=1
    return position

#Presentation
print("This program find all the repeated values ​​in a list and they tell you in what position they are")
print("First you have to make a list for that tell me")

#Input
while True:
    try:
        elements=int(input("How many items does this list have? "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Please write the number of elements with numeric and integer characters")

print("Tell me the items on this list. They can be of any type")
list=[]
counter=0
while counter != elements:
    value=input("-> ")
    list.append(value)
    counter += 1
#From here we already insert a list with n elements and name each element

#Now we have to see if there are repeated values

unique = []
k=0
while k != elements:
    element=list[k]
    position=count_repeated(list,element)
    if element not in unique:
        if len(position)==1:
            print (element,"repeats once in position",position)
        else:
            print (element,"is repeated",len(position),"times in positions",position)
        unique.append(element)
    k += 1
```

And this is an example of what it prints

```
This program find all the repeated values ​​in a list and they tell you in what position they are
First you have to make a list for that tell me

How many items does this list have? 7
Tell me the items on this list. They can be of any type

-> #

-> 2.6

-> a

-> 7

-> #

-> 2.6

-> #
# is repeated 3 times in positions [0, 4, 6]
2.6 is repeated 2 times in positions [1, 5]
a repeats once in position [2]
7 repeats once in position [3]
```

I hope you enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely not the best way to do it but you said you just wanted to see it done with a dictionary, so here you go.

```
#Presentation
print("This program find all the repeated values ​​in a list and they tell you in what position they are")
print("First you have to make a list for that tell me")
#Input
elements=int(input("How many items does this list have? "))
print("Tell me the items on this list")
dicts = {}
counter=0
while counter != elements:
    a=int(input("=>"))
    dicts[counter] = a
    counter=counter+1 
  
rev_dict = {} 
for key, value in dicts.items(): 
    rev_dict.setdefault(value, set()).add(key) 
  
  
result = filter(lambda x: len(x)>1, rev_dict.values())
for x in result:
    print("At Positions " + str(x) + " The Value is " + str(dicts[next(iter(x))]))
```

A good resource for what your doing https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-find-keys-with-duplicate-values-in-dictionary/